# SSO Implementation ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, single-sign-on

This is a very basic question. I want to do an SSO integration using ColdFusion but do not know where to start. I found the website `ssoeasy.com` through a google search, but am very confused about how to use it and where to find documentation.

I think it has something related with `cfldap` or `cfhttp` but not sure what and where:

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="http://testsso.com/login.cfm">
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Are you looking to write an sso application or make a cf application available to one?

Comment: i am working on one application and need to do a connect with sso, the company 1-4-16 [for privacy i had hidden the name, you can copy this numbers and convert to the letters]

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what role you want to play in an SSO ecosystem. Are you an app in a larger federation (Service Provider), or are you trying to implement an SSO style login across multiple applications that you control, or are you looking to setup so that your users can log in with Google or Facebook or such other identity registers?

A few years back we did an implementation with Shibboleth (https://shibboleth.net/) and CF where our intended place in the system would be that of a Service Provider to other companies Identity Providers.  It works pretty straight forward as we let Shibboleth handle all the SAML federation grunt work and then when it's completed we get an e-mail address (the unique identifier we decided on) back from Shibboleth saying that the user has been authenticated via the Identity Provider.

Other 'SSO' implementations are around for other types of integrations.

From CFCs to handle OAuth -- https://github.com/coldfumonkeh/oauth2

To integrated oauth support if you're running a new enough version of ColdFusion https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-m-o/cfoauth.html

Hope this is of assistance to you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your SSO use case, the application will be a cloud service provider (SP). There are three things you need to determine to help in the selection of the appropriate technology, mainly (1) SSO protocol to integrate, mainly SAML, OAuth, OpenID Connect (OIDC), etc. (2) Hosting, mainly Cloud, On-Prem, or hybrid, and (3) whether or not IdP discovery is needed for your business partners.

Being ColdFusion based as well as working to be a cloud SP web application, my experience is that the application is to be hosted by your organization, such that an on premise SSO capability is desired, as well as IdP Discovery will be needed for your partners.

As noted in your question there are some options for integration. I have found the most popular approach to being a SP website is to utilize a vendor product that handles the SSO protocol (e.g. SAML, OIDC) where the integration with your ColdFusion application is based upon a simple REST API integration. With this design pattern, the vendor product manages all the security of the SSO protocol and then simplifies integration to your application as a secure REST API exchange of identity information.  This will minimize the impact to your application and also give the most support for modern identity. One product that offers this capability is PingFederate via the Agentless integration (also referred to as Reference ID integration).  I have had much success integrating ColdFusion applications following this type of approach.

Answer (score 0):

SAML seemed to be the easiest to implement for our team. Phil Duba's 2013 Beyond Encrypt() presentation is a good starting place. His website is down right now, but I'm sure you can find the downloadable file somewhere. Learning about SAML in general would be a good idea. Also, you can use Java, so maybe look at SAML/OAUTH Java examples and try doing that for Coldfusion since it is based on Java.